# SSIS (File System Task) - Unable to move file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411741/how-to-loop-through-excel-files-and-load-them-into-a-database-using-ssis-package) on how to loop through all the excels in a folder and loop through excel sheets.

And everthing went on fine, it works as I excpected.

But after the For Each Loop Container for the sheets, I've added a File System Task to move the file to archive folder. And I get a error like this

> [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".

**NOTE: File System Task is added inside the For Each Loop Container of the excel files.**

I guess the error is because of the ADO.NET connection which was estasblished for that particular excel file.

I'm having a very hard time with this, any suggestion or help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the foreach loop (and outside of it), write a script task that use the file system object to move all the files.

Comment: How can we use a script task and move all the files at once to archive?

Comment: I don't understand the question.   It's a script task.   You can program it to do anything.   It can use the file system object to move files.   What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Try the solutions here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758209/ssis-for-each-file-loop-and-file-system-task-to-copy-files